# ECMAScript pull parser

Tags: javascript, parsing, ecmascript-6, minify

There seems to be a lot of resources for XML pull parsing, but is it possible to build a pull parser for JavaScript? Why is this not something people pursue? Pull parsing enables to stream the file while parsing it, which allows for infinitely sized files (for example) and concurrent use.

The problem I encounter is that I need to divide the code into certain small units. I thought statements would be a good way to split the code. Each call to the pull parser would yield another statement (or function declaration). However this goes wrong with function expressions. They require to split the statements up because each statement could contain a function with more statements.

How would I go about implementing such a parser? Or do you think this is an unwise design?

I'm trying to build a fast minifier.

EDIT: see http://www.infoq.com/articles/HIgh-Performance-Parsers-in-Java-V2 for more info on sequential access parsers. They only describe JSON and XML...

Also see https://github.com/qfox/zeparser2 for a fast streaming JS parser.

EDIT2:

I can think of a few options:

- return each grammar type, even nested ones. So (most) tokens will be returned multiple times in different grammars (like an expression inside a statement). So for example you first return the statement 'var a = b + c;' and then return the expression 'b + c'. So as caller you can check if the returned grammar is a var-statement and do something with that...
- work with event function, this is push-parsing. Like call the var-statement handler, or expression handler.
- full blown AST generation with early return?

Comment: There are lots of statement nesting grammar constructions in JavaScript. To implement an effective minifier, I'd be surprised if you didn't end up needing a complete AST anyway.

Comment: Most of the minifying is sequential. Removing whitespace, semicolons and variable renaming is all sequential. If we omit code rewriting/optimization that is pretty much all you need for a minifier.

Comment: So what is your exact question? You don't seem to be asking for a library, as you already found one (and it would be off-topic anyway).

Comment: Well, ZeParser seems to implement it, though not sure how exactly. But besides, I'm working in Go and intent to implement the parser myself.

Comment: @TacodeWolff: I'd recommend to use iterators then, and write your parser in the form of a generator function.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "return each grammar type, even nested ones". How would this lead to a token being emitted multiple times?

Comment: @Bergi What exactly would that work? Do you have an example of this? I've updated the question to reflect the ambiguity.

Comment: @TacodeWolff: Nonono, don't emit strings. When the "caller wants to check if its a var statement", the caller does not want to parse anything. Your parser should already do this. Have a look at [shift](https://github.com/shapesecurity/shift-spec) or [estree](https://github.com/estree/estree), and try to follow these closely. Instead of nesting, you might want to return a "subgenerator" per element, that can be iterated by itself, or jumped over by simply advancing the parent generator.

Comment: @Bergi Ah, sounds interesting! So for example a generator that returns the next statement every time, which contains a subgenerator that returns subexpressions or something? Shift seems to return the full AST so I'm not sure what you're referring to. Estree defines all AST types only...

Comment: @TacodeWolff: Yes, exactly that's the idea. Those links were only for demonstration of what "nesting" will be appropriate, but I also think that you should follow their interface conventions (property names, types of AST objects etc) as close as possible (but use generators instead of arrays).